# MySQL Join returns too many rows with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join

I am having trouble with a SQL query. So in my project user can reserve a ride. I want to display reserved rides by users ID (`passenger_id`) but query returns all users (`driver_id`) advertisements when user reserved a ride only for one of drivers advertisements.

```
    SELECT advertisement.id
         , COUNT(review.driver_id) AS 'review_count'
         , ROUND(AVG(review.mark) ,1) AS 'rating'
         , users.unique_id
         , users.name
         , users.surname
         , users.phone
         , YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(users.birthdate) AS age
         , users.image
         , advertisement.from_city
         , advertisement.to_city
         , users.car_name
         , users.car_model
         , users.car_make_year
         , advertisement.number_of_places
         , advertisement.price
         , advertisement.datetime
         , advertisement.info
      FROM reserved_rides
      JOIN advertisement  
        ON reserved_rides.driver_id = advertisement.user_id
      LEFT 
      JOIN review 
        ON reserved_rides.driver_id = review.driver_id
      JOIN users 
        ON reserved_rides.driver_id = users.unique_id
     WHERE reserved_rides.passenger_id = ?
     GROUP 
        BY advertisement.id
     ORDER 
        BY advertisement.datetime ASC
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: you can replace 'GROUP BY advertisement.id' with 'GROUP BY reserved_rides.passenger_id '

Comment: @KirstenPhukon Thank you! With `GROUP BY reserved_rides.passenger_id` is not what I wanted but I replaced `GROUP BY advertisement.id` with `GROUP BY reserved_rides.driver_id` and it worked. Please post answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can illustrate the problem with a simpler query, although in general, if it appears in the SELECT clause, and it isn't aggregated, then it must also appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope replacing `GROUP BY advertisement.id` with `GROUP BY reserved_rides.driver_id`solves your problem. cheers